# Rust function return type with lifetime value

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, rust-rocket

I'd like to implement the `Responder` trait for my `Hero` structure, but the following method signature (`respond_to`):

```rust
use rocket::{http::Status, response::Responder, Request, Response};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Hero {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
    pub identity: String,
    pub hometown: String,
    pub age: i32,
}

impl Hero {
    pub fn new(
        num: Option<i32>,
        name: String,
        identity: String,
        hometown: String,
        age: i32,
    ) -> Hero {
        Hero {
            id: num,
            name,
            identity,
            hometown,
            age,
        }
    }
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r> for Hero {
    fn respond_to(self, _request: &Request) -> Result<Response, Status> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Throws a compilation error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:32:55
   |
32 |     fn respond_to(self, _request: &Request) -> Result<Response, Status> {
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say which one of `_request`'s 2 lifetimes it is borrowed from
```

Dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.2"
serde = {version = "1.0.99", features=["derive"]}
```

The documentation doesn't provide an example of how to provide lifetimes when a type is returned. How to specify lifetime when a type is returned?

Comment: How did you define your trait? There seems no problem on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6b46e930c07bb81f45775e19db67584)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]: we can't tell what types you are using. In particular, what is `Response` and how is it defined?

Comment: @Jmb Yep, the playground doesn't have any issues compiling. But, when I do `cargo build` it does have this error. `$rustc -V
rustc 1.39.0-nightly (bea0372a1 2019-08-20)`
`$cargo -V
cargo 1.39.0-nightly (3f700ec43 2019-08-19)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Responder` trait is defined as:

```rust
pub trait Responder<'r> {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &Request) -> response::Result<'r>;
}
```

The `response::Result<'r>` is defined as:

```rust
pub type Result<'r> = ::std::result::Result<self::Response<'r>, ::http::Status>;
```

Your method signature is:

```rust
fn respond_to(self, request: &Request) -> Result<Response, Status>;
```

As you can see, you just forgot to specify lifetime for the `Response`. The correct method signature is:

```rust
impl<'r> Responder<'r> for Hero {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &Request) -> Result<Response<'r>, Status> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```